# AUGraph/AudioUnit support in Rdio iOS SDK

Tags: ios, rdio

I wanted to develop a iOS music player app by using Rdio streaming service.I have gone through rdio sdk documentation and able to understand the audio playback API's. However along with playback, I would also want to add some of the default apple provided audio effects like equalizers etc to audio stream. I could not find any way to do it so.
Is rdio iOS SDK allow us to add audio effects to its pipeline or is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rdio iOS SDK doesn't let you integrate with AUGraph/AudioUnit. The SDK is designed to work like a [blackbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box), you specify what to play and music comes out the speakers. This is done to prevent developers from accessing and manipulating the audio.